# Reverse Proxy on Nginx from one server to another

Tags: nginx, sails.js, reverse-proxy, pm2

I am trying to access a `Sails` app running on `pm2`. The application runs if I access it directly from the IP of the server on which it is running.

When I run Nginx as a reverse proxy on another server, the below happens:

When I use the below configuration on `origin.myserver.com`, it still works:

```
server {
 listen 80;

 location / {
   client_max_body_size    10m;
   client_body_buffer_size 128k;

   proxy_send_timeout   600;
   proxy_read_timeout   600;
   proxy_buffer_size    128k;
   proxy_buffers     4 256k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://dest.myserver:1337;

   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

However, when I try adding multiple sub-directories from Nginx, it doesn't work:

```
server {
 listen 80;

 location /auth {
   client_max_body_size    10m;
   client_body_buffer_size 128k;

   proxy_send_timeout   600;
   proxy_read_timeout   600;
   proxy_buffer_size    128k;
   proxy_buffers     4 256k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://dest.myserver:1337;

   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
2017/08/11 15:55:13 [error] 8304#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/locales/locale.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: IP, server: , request: "GET /locales/locale.js?v=1502466823352 HTTP/1.1", host: "REVERSE PROXY IP"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the below configuration:

Since the services were running on `Node/PM2` directly, the subpath will not be forwarded if we use `/` after the location path.
So for applications running without Nginx, we use `location /auth/` instead of `location /auth`.

And we need to forward the headers and data also.

If the application being forwarded to, runs on Nginx, the path is forwarded if we use `location /auth/` i.e. service called would be `http://myserver.com:1337/auth`

Example for my case would be:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location /auth/ {
        proxy_set_header Host origin.myserver.com/auth/;
        proxy_pass http://dest.myserver.com:1337/;

        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_send_timeout   600;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
        proxy_buffer_size    128k;
        proxy_buffers     4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://someother.domain.in';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
```